# Is only imperative allowed for “bonvolu”?

Tags: word-usage

Can “bonvolu” only be used in imperative? E.g. does it make sense to say “Li bonvolas”?

Answer (score 3):

[PIV](https://vortaro.net/#bonvoli_kd) has some examples with other than *u-modo* of the verb *bonvoli*:

- *eminentaj personoj, kiuj bonvolis eniri en la honoran komitaton* (Z)
- *princa moŝto, ĉu vi ne bonvolos ripozi?* (Z)

But as you can see the style is quite formal and old, so I doubt if any other form than *bonvolu* or *bonvole* are used today. Both of these are used to form *ĝentila peto* and while

- *Bonvolu sidi ĉi tie!*

is the more common way, the recent alternative

- *Bonvole sidu ĉi tie!*

is also a logical and acceptable way to express "Please, be seated/take a seat". Note, that Zamenhof used neither, but expressions that are no longer used. For further info see [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html).

Answer (score 2):

`Bonvoli` means something like "be so kind as to agree to ..." (Esti tiel bona, ke oni afable konsentas - [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#bonvoli_kdc))

You can use it also as an adverb:

> kiuj bonvole oferis gastamon (Paroladoj de Zamenhof)

or as any other verb:

> Ĉu vi bonvolas supreniri, sinjoro? (La batalo de l'vivo, Zamenhof)

> does it make sense to say “Li bonvolas”?

If the context is clear, then yes, but you should have already mentioned the action that goes with `bonvoli`. Otherwise no, you need to say what the subject is agreeing to do or consider.

The -u form `bonvolu` can be understood as a `please` in `please take a seat`.